# Detecting color of an image stored in the database

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, image, db2, database

So what I want to do is store images inside a database and not on the file system. And after storing them, i want to detect whether the image is coloured or black& white, crop the image to a size i specify later, etc.

Also, I don't want to get the image manipulation done via the overlying application like Java, C# or PhP as my database may be indirectly accessed without using any overlying application.

For storing images, I checked the following DBMS's:

1. Oracle Multimedia(formerly Intermedia) but couldn't really find an image manipulation documentation, also the installation of different modules is rather confusing.
2. IBM DB2 and even though the image extenders have been discontinued, I have found a suitable third party image processing library, ImageMagick. From whatever I have read this is the most suitable database with the extension for my requirement, but i am a bit skeptical about its usefulness as its pretty old (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0504stolze/ <- This was written in 2005)
3. SQL server with Filestream where I can store images as BLOB, but i am again not sure about how can I fulfill my requirements.
4. MongoDB with GridFS, and this also helps in storing images but not exactly manipulating.

I am now lost and require a direction where I can proceed so that I am not stuck anymore at choosing a suitable DB. Any alternative DBMS or method to do the things I want are more than welcome.

Comment: I think you will find that you are disappointed with any of these choices. None of these are image editors, they are databases. They are not designed to evaluate the content of image files. If you want to manipulate images you should use a program designed for that sort of thing. Databases are designed for storing data and they do it quite well.

Comment: As @Sean Lange said.  Overall, any image manipulation "in" the DB is probably better described as image manipulation proximally triggered by a DB event.  One or another piece of image-manipulation software (such as ImageMagick) will be leveraged for the purpose, likely via a custom function in the DB.  Probably any DB that supports user-defined external functions can be made to do it.

Comment: You should store this information in other fields so you can query them. Do not try to evaluate this info real-time. IE, if you allow 3 sizes of thumbs, store the 3 sizes, don't convert it when they ask for it.  But, if you are required, I know you can do this with MSSQL if you use CLR. Just don't expect it to be fast.

Comment: I would urge you to think twice before storing vast quantities of images in a database - you tend to get a great big amorphous glob of a information that is hard to back up and manage. I would think about storing the images as files in a filesystem and just put references to them in the database. YMMV of course.

Comment: Thanks +Sean, +John, +Steve and +Mark for all the help, we are finally using Oracle Multimedia for our implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In software world (and not only there) people are making things that does one thing, but they try to make it in such a way, that this one thing will be done perfectly. It does not make sense much sense to create a database that no only store information, but also be an image editor, video clips enhancer and a text reader.

It is better to make it just a database and if it is so much in need, create 3 other programs for each of this task.

Therefore you will not find a database which will fulfill your requirements, store images in your database if you want so and then calculate your color, resize them on the application layer. If you need to do this often - then store them in database, precalculate and preresize things you need and store them in database as well. Then query based on precalculated values.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, we are finally using Oracle Multimedia after learning about the intricacies involved. It helps in calculating image information and storing in columns of the database as well, almost something which we were searching for.